# Error adding a column to a typed dataset

Tags: c#, xsd, strongly-typed-dataset

I am trying to add a new column to my existing dataset for some reasons when I am trying create an instance of the dataset it threw me the following error

```
Error   47  The type 'System.Data.TypedTableBase`1<T0>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

my dataset name is `MainReceive.xsd` for which I am creating an instance as follows

```
private gsiMainReceive.gsi_main_receiveDataTable dtMainReceiving;
```

May I know what exactly is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

That error mssg is pretty specific.
If you add a reference in the project to System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll  using System.Data; will enable you to use the Extended APIs contained on DataSetExtensions.

So use:

```
using System.Data;
```

Comment: I already have that included as I was using the dataset before and I just added a new column